# IIS logging requests for XML by literals

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, logging, xml

How can I turn on logging for hits on XML files that are requested by literals on .aspx pages?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "requested by literals"? I'm assuming this means you are generating the XML file to download on the fly, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that is a very confusing question. I guess, if you had to do it, you could enable "audit logging" using the NTFS tools on your windows server for those XML files.. assuming the aspx script loads them directly.. if they are loaded remotely.. dunno. If they are loaded from the page, then the requests should appear in your IIS service logs.